# QOpenGLTexture (Qt) from raw data (freeimage)

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, freeimage

I've been using the old Qt OpenGl methods but it was about time to switch to the newer ones.

being *bitmap* a FIBITMAP* properly initialized

> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height,0,
>   GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)FreeImage_GetBits(pImage));

worked like a charm for me.

But now in the newer methods it is preferred to use *QOpenGLTexture*

Unfortunatly my tries were unsucessful ie.

> QOpenGLTexture*qtexture = new
>   QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
>
> texture->setData(QOpenGLTexture::PixelFormat::RGBA,
>   QOpenGLTexture::PixelType::Int8,FreeImage_GetBits(bitmap));

that code returns a 1x1 texture but also if I force the size like using

> qtexture->setSize(width,height,4);

qtexture has the proper size but it is totally black, also I've tried to search in Qt/Freeimage forums etc but nothing related unfortunatly everyone uses QImage to feed QOpenGLTexture but unfortunatly I need to support some "strange" fileformats like .hdr or .exr that are not supported by Qt itself.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2):

For a `QOpenGLTexture`, you have to set `Size`, `Format` before `allocateStorage`. The last step is `setData`.

```
QOpenGLTexture *text = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
text->setMinMagFilters(QOpenGLTexture::Linear, QOpenGLTexture::Linear);
text->create();

// given some `width`, `height` and `data_ptr`
text->setSize(width, height, 1);
text->setFormat(QOpenGLTexture::RGBA8_UNorm);
text->allocateStorage();
text->setData(QOpenGLTexture::Red, QOpenGLTexture::UInt8, data_ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

> qtexture->allocateStorage();

was the key!

Comment: What is the advantage of using QOpenGLTexture object instead of pure OpenGL?

Comment: That's the Qt wrapper that is easier to use with a Qt OpenGL widget